# What is the porper way to get user input in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, forms

Should I use ASP elements with a `runat="server"` attribute or an HTML form?

It seems like using ASP tags such as `<asp:TextBox>` is much more comfortable since I don't have to redirect the user to another page on a form submition, but also from what I've seen, it seemed like HTML forms are the more accepted way. I was starting to wonder if using ASP elements increases server load or has any other disadvantage?

In case I should use ASP elements, how do I validate the input with Javascript before sending it to the server?

In case I should use HTML forms, how do I not redirect the user on submition and also not run the server code on page load?

Comment: It's a pretty broad question - viewstate is an overhead in asp.net webforms when using asp:controls, so you can either use asp.net mvc which utilizes html 5 controls, or keep with webforms using html5 controls and post them using ajax (In which case you're probably best just going the mvc route anyway)

Comment: ViewState is only an overhead if you don't know what you're doing. I am building high performance sites in Web Forms every day and usually top the performance of MVC sites for the simple reason that people do stupid things irrespective of the technology.

Answer (score -1):

You can easily use the HTML5 input type in Web Forms by adding the runat="server" attribute, so that it can be accessed on the server-side:

```
<label for="name">Name:</label>

<input type="text" id="name" name="name" required
       minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10" runat="server">
```

Note, on the server-side you will access it via the Value property of the input element, not with the Text property of a typical ASP.NET textbox control.

Contrary to what a lot of people think, ViewState only ever becomes a problem when people do silly things like nesting data-bound controls, in which case it can become bloated very quickly.

Not sure what you're asking regarding validation... but you still have options like this on both client and server. If you're working with an existing Web Forms project, I would stick with regular  ASP.NET controls and keep it simple. This way, you can have out-of-the-box validation on both client and server.